# Ng-transclude data from template in link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written the following Angular directive:

```
angular.module('solarquote.directives', []).directive('editfield', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<span ng-hide="editorEnabled" ng-transclude></span>' +   // viewable field
  '<span ng-show="editorEnabled"><input class="input-medium" ng-model="editableField"></span>', // editable field
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.editorEnabled = false;
        scope.editableField = elm.children[0].children[0].innerText;
     }
  };
})
```

And in the html, inside a ng-repeat:

```
<span editfield>{{ item.fields.name }}</span>
```

I would like to prepopulate the input field in the directive's template with the same content in the ng-transclude. Going through the DOM and grabbing the text yields:  {{ item.fields.name }} instead of the rendered data: "Bob" (or whatever name).

What is the best way to access the transcluded data?

Thanks

Comment: you can not just simply put into `ng-model` the transcluded value (`{{model}}`) as you can write any expression there `{{ }}` . you'll have to use syntax like `<span editfield="item.fields.name">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to assign to `ng-model` an expression that you specify in transclusion block. This is because a transclusion block can be an expression like `{{ functionValue() }}` or `{{ field1+':'+field2 }}`. Angular simply does not know how to reverse those expressions.

What you can do, is provide a reference to the model you want to update. See the following punkler http://plunker.co/edit/NeEzetsbPEwpXzCl7kI1?p=preview (needs jQuery)

```
directive('editfield', function() {

  var template = ''+
    '<span ng-show="editorEnabled"><input class="input-medium" ng-model="editfield"></span>'+
    '<span ng-hide="editorEnabled" ng-transclude></span>';

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: template,
    scope:{
      editfield:'='
    },
    transclude:true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var input = element.find('input');
      input.on('blur',function(){
        scope.editorEnabled=false;
        scope.$apply();
      });
      element.bind('click',function(){
        scope.editorEnabled=!scope.editorEnabled;
        scope.$apply();
        input.focus();
      })
     }
  };
})
```